Dumb Move? Lost Staking Rewards
I think I made a major knucklehead move here. I misplaced my Yoroi seed so I had to pull my balance out to another wallet. I undelegated (including my 2 ADA) before withdrawal my staking rewards and it appears they are gone. Any possible way to restore them or did they get reverted back to the Treasury and gone forever?

Which wallet? Some wallets (eg Daedalus) automatically include staking rewards on any outgoing transaction.
You should be able to lookup in a blockchain explorer the last transaction out of that wallet to see if the staking rewards were included.

Yoroi. I looked it up and the staking rewards, unfortunately, were not included in the transfer. I have a feeling the coins were reverted back to the Treasury. I know it was a dumb move on my part, but I am irked at Yoroi that they would not automatically withdraw rewards with a undelegation request.
